# Azure yaml pipeline group variables not seen by task in a template file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a pipeline stage that is using a template as follows:

```
# Deploy to AKS
- stage: DeployTEST
  displayName: Test env for my-app
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  variables:
  - group: 'my-app-var-group-test'
  - group: 'package-variables'
  - template: templates/shared-template-vars.yml@templates
  jobs:
  - deployment: TestDeployment
    displayName: Deploy to AKS - Test
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: env-test
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - template: ./aks/deployment-steps.yml
```

...and the content of the template `deployment-steps.yml` is:

```
steps:
- script: |
    echo AzureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
    echo KubernetesServiceConnection: '$(kubernetesServiceConnection)' # this is working

- task: KubernetesManifest@0
  displayName: Create imagePullSecret
  inputs:
    action: createSecret
    secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
    dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    kubernetesServiceConnection: $(kubernetesServiceConnection) # this is causing an error
```

I get an error like this:

> `There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job TestDeployment: Step input kubernetesServiceConnection references service connection $(kubernetesServiceConnection) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."`

and like this when I try to select individual stages prior manual pipeline run:

> Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
> `Job TestDeployment: Step  input kubernetesServiceConnection references service connection $(kubernetesServiceConnection) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.`

The errors above are misleading, because it is not an authorization issue:

- the referenced K8s service connection is authorized
- when I hardcode the value of the `$(kubernetesServiceConnection)` variable the pipeline runs just fine - no errors
- variable group `my-app-var-group-test` is authorized - **IMPORTANT**: this is where the `$(kubernetesServiceConnection)` variable is defined

**NOTE:** The variable `kubernetesServiceConnection` is defined in the `my-app-var-group-test` variable group & when I comment out the KubernetesManifest task, the value of the `$(kubernetesServiceConnection)` variable is properly printed to the pipeline console output without any issues and the pipeline runs successfully!?

I know I could use parameters to pass values into the template, but this setup is already used by all other pipelines (variable group vars are used/references in templates) and this issue appeared on a newly created pipeline. I have used file comparison to compare the yaml of a working pipeline and this one and failed to spot anything...

I might be missing something obvious, but I spent hours on this failing to resolve the error...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues while passing variable groups parameter to template from azure pipeline.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72557416/issues-while-passing-variable-groups-parameter-to-template-from-azure-pipeline-y)

Comment: @VinceBowdren - Thank you for the link to this other issue. It does add some value but my case is different - I am not using parameters to pas the value from the variable group; also as I said in the question I already have existing pipeline that use the exact setup, but this error came up on a newly created pipeline and I am struggling to find the root cause.

Comment: the crucial point is that you are declaring the kubernetesServiceConnection variable at a lower level (in your case stage level); but _in order to be used to define a task's service connection_ the variable must be declared at the top level i.e. in the pipeline. It's a known restriction.

Comment: @VinceBowdren - I can declare empty variable at root level, but will the variable from the var group value take precedence?

Comment: No, the service account variable you use (and its value) has to be declared at root level.

Comment: @VinceBowdren - thanks for your help I will get to the bottom of it; The issue I have is that different stages are using different values of the `kubernetesServiceConnection` as well as `azureSubscription` for example; this has worked so far on existing pipelines... I am aware of the compile vs runtime issues with stages and var groups, but I have existing pipelines using the same pattern; If I have to design the pipeline my self I would use [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)